# Are these parametrizations of the same curve?

Tags: derivatives, parametric, parametrization

I've a doubt concerning parametrization of $f(x) = x^2$. 
I'm studying curves can be parametrized in different ways, changing the speed with which they travel their path.
I'm pretty sure that if I'll write,
                       $$ f(t)=(t,t^2)$$
 and
$$  f(t)=(2t,4t^2)$$
they represents the same curve travelled with different speed.

I'm not sure about it if we write something like,
$$ f(t)=(t^2,t^4)$$

 Does the fact that the components of the latter aren't anymore multiples of the previous ones change something?

 I know the question can seem a bit ambiguous and wide, but any explanation or advice on the topic is welcomed with enthusiasm!

Comment: $f(2t, 4t^2)$ would be the correct parameterization.   But the speed at which you move along the curve is irrelevant.  All that matters is that for any $t$, you map to a unique (and the correct) $(x,y)$.  There is a problem with $f(t^2,t^4)$ if the domain of $x$ includes the negative real numbers.

Comment: Second is $(2t,4t^2)$.

Comment: I suggest writing explicitly the coordinates $x$, $y$ and using different letters for different parameters. For instance, at the beginning you have that $y=x^2$ can be represented by $x=t$, then obviously $y=t^2$. If you say $x=2 u$, then $y=x^2\neq 2 u^2$; then $x=v^2$, $y=x^2=v^4$. The parameter is arbitrary.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys, Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your notation is a bit muddy but your question is a good one.

To clear the notation, your first parameterization is 
$$\left\{ \matrix{ x=t\\f = t^2}
\right.
$$
and your second is 
$$
\left\{ \matrix{ x=2t\\f = 2t^2}
\right.
$$
and these are not equivalent curves; but if you meant 
$$
\left\{ \matrix{ x=2t\\f = (2t)^2}
\right.
$$
then those would be equivalent only with different "speeds" along the two parameterizations.

Your third curve 
$$
\left\{ \matrix{ x=t^2\\f = (t^{2})^{2} }
\right.
$$
would be the same except for one important fact:  The range of $x$ is no longer $(-\infty,\infty)$, it is instead $(0,\infty)$.  So this is a parameterization of only the left half of the original curve.

That is, you have the right idea but you need to be careful that the range of $x$ is fully covered.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know it can be very boring answering this kind of questions, so I appreciate it even more! thank you also for pointing out the mistake and answering anyway!